# <DNN:ICON> control has no CssClass support

Tags: c#, class, dotnetnuke, containers, partial

Implementing a container that uses the DotNetNuke's standard icon.

```
<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True"
            Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="icon" 
             Src="~/Admin/Containers/Icon.ascx" %>  

<dnn:icon id="dnnICON" runat="server" CssClass="img-circle" />
```

This renders the HTML module onto the page but does not pass the css class name, therefore the image is unstyled.

Editing /admin/containers/icon.ascx.cs I've added the following code:

```
namespace DotNetNuke.UI.Containers
{
  public partial class Icon : SkinObjectBase
  {
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
            {
                imgIcon.CssClass = CssClass;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect of passing CSS Classes to the HTML module in the page and doesn't seem to have broken anything BUT I'm concerned that as soon as an upgrade overwrites the admin directory all my changes will be wiped out.

Is there a correct way to do this using a file within the skin folders? Can I do it from within the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the dnn:icon control in a DIV and target it that way.

```
<div class="dnnIcon"><dnn:icon id="dnnICON" runat="server" CssClass="img-circle" /></div>
```

then in your CSS do something like

```
.dnnIcon IMG{ STYLE GOES HERE }
```

You are correct that making such a change as you have will be lost during your next DNN upgrade unless you redo the change there as well.

Another option would be to submit a Pull request on GitHub to the dnn platform project to see if DNN Corp will include your change in a future release so you can target the icon specifically without having to do it manually either through code or through my suggested method.

Comment: For a simple change like that, it's a pretty high likelihood that your pull request would be accepted.  See http://dnn-connect.org/community/blogs/contributing-to-the-dnn-platform-using-git-and-github for a walkthrough on doing that.  Since you're only editing one file, you can probably do it through GitHub itself (click Edit button on https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/development/Website/admin/Containers/Icon.ascx.cs, which will create a fork and branch, from which you can submit a pull request)

Comment: Excellent documentation on the dnn-connect site @bdukes, thanks. I've taken the first step in opensource contribution and submitted a pull request as Chris suggested. Have got a warm fuzzy feeling.